# How do I center an error message inside an html table?

Tags: html, css

I have html code that prints all of the posts inside an html table.

However, if there are no posts then I need to print an error `No posts found`.

Now focus on the error message

I am trying to print the error message in the center of the table.

```
<style>
table{border-collapse:collapse}
td{background-color:white;padding:10px}
.first_tr td{background-color:#f1f7f7 !important;border-bottom:1px red solid}
</style>
<table border="0" width="400px">
<tr class="first_tr"><td width="20%">POST ID</td><td width="79%">POST TITLE</td></tr>
<tr><td>No posts found</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/9UhTd/

The error message is shown in the begin of the table, but I am trying to center it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, you're missing a colspan attribute on your second row's only cell

```
<table border="0" width="400px">
<tr class="first_tr"><td width="20%">POST ID</td><td width="79%">POST TITLE</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">No user found</td></tr>
</table>​​​​​
```

Without it, that cell will only take up the space of the cell above it. With that resolved you can go on to center it how ever you please

```
<table border="0" width="400px">
<tr class="first_tr"><td width="20%">POST ID</td><td width="79%">POST TITLE</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">No user found</td></tr>
</table>​​​​​
```

or

```
<style type="text/css">.center { text-align: center; }</style>
<table border="0" width="400px">
<tr class="first_tr"><td width="20%">POST ID</td><td width="79%">POST TITLE</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" class="center">No user found</td></tr>
</table>​​​​​
```

[Your jsfiddle with this implemented](http://jsfiddle.net/9UhTd/2/)

Answer (score 1):

you were missing colspan

the code below should do

```
<style>
table{border-collapse:collapse}
td{background-color:white;padding:10px}
.first_tr td{background-color:#f1f7f7 !important;border-bottom:1px red solid}
</style>
<table border="0" width="400px">
<tr class="first_tr"><td width="20%">POST ID</td><td width="79%">POST TITLE</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">No user found</td></tr>
</table>​
```

Comment: this answer also is very useful, and it same of Josh's Answer, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Few comments:
1)  If you make it so your  element spans 2 columns since your table has 2 columns using:
colspan="2"

2) you can add a class to the  element something like class="error" and add this style to your css:

```
.error{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Yup, i do this already, but the problem was in the colspan, this is first time i hear about colspan, i always see it.. but it first time i know it is very important